# Thread.Join() changes program output in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is a slightly modified version of one of the sample programs give in C# in a Nutshell :

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace SemaphorTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static Semaphore gate = new Semaphore(3, 3);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(Enter);
                t.Start(i);
            }
        }

        public static void Enter(Object id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread " + id + " wants to enter.");
            gate.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Thread " + id + " is in.");
            Thread.Sleep(500 * (Int32)id);
            Console.WriteLine("Thread " + id + " leaving.");
            gate.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

This prints the following output (seemingly in random order) :

```
Thread 0 wants to enter.
Thread 1 wants to enter.
Thread 1 is in.
Thread 0 is in.
Thread 2 wants to enter.
Thread 3 wants to enter.
Thread 0 leaving.
Thread 3 is in.
Thread 4 wants to enter.
Thread 2 is in.
Thread 1 leaving.
Thread 4 is in.
Thread 2 leaving.
Thread 3 leaving.
Thread 4 leaving.
```

However, adding a Thread.Join() as follows changes the output drastically.ie:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(Enter);
                t.Start(i);
                t.Join();
            }
```

Changes the output to :

```
Thread 0 wants to enter.
Thread 0 is in.
Thread 0 leaving.
Thread 1 wants to enter.
Thread 1 is in.
Thread 1 leaving.
Thread 2 wants to enter.
Thread 2 is in.
Thread 2 leaving.
Thread 3 wants to enter.
Thread 3 is in.
Thread 3 leaving.
Thread 4 wants to enter.
Thread 4 is in.
Thread 4 leaving.
```

Why does this happen ? I know that these threads are foreground threads by default and that the Main thread doesn't need to wait for them to complete (they will run even after Main completes so they won't require a thread.Join() here). But I don't understand what makes them run in the order as they were created after the change. Any ideas ?

```
Thanks
Dileep Balakrishnan
```

Comment: The `Join()` makes it a single-threaded app.

Comment: The `Join()` makes it *behave as if it were* a single-threaded app

Comment: @spender - stating `t.Start(); t.Join();` leaves very little room (time) for any multithreading. A smart jitter might even optimize this away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

Because you've asked it to!

You've started one thread, then waited for it to finish, then started the next thread etc. That's precisely what `Thread.Join` does: it blocks the currently executing thread until the thread you've called it on terminates.

What I'm interested in is what you *expected* that code to do... If you just wanted to wait until all the threads had finished before letting the main thread complete, you need to start all the threads, remembering them as you go, and *then* call `Join` on each on in turn. For example:

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
// First start all the threads
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(Enter);
    t.Start(i);
    threads.Add(t);
}

// Then wait for them to finish
foreach (var thread in threads)
{
    thread.Join();
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, I wrote the same code just as you pointed out after reading your post(of course, without your comments :)). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You are joining each thread with the calling thread.  This will essentially block the calling thread and wait for each thread to end in turn.

In the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx) it states:

> Blocks the calling thread until a thread terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.join() does not make things run concurrently. It actually enforces the behaviour you're seeing by blocking the current thread until it's completed.
This is mentioned clearly in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx